# Windows Phone Application Bar's Icons colors

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-phone-7.1

When does exactly the color of appbar's icon changes (that is, from white to black, or drom black to white)? When the theme is switched from black to white, or when the background brush of Application Bar is changed? What I if I want to apply my own custom theme, so that the application bar is always white? I use black icons, but will they turn to white in Dark theme, even thouh the app bar is white (as it was customly changed)?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

All the icons used in the ApplicationBar should be 48x48 PNG files, white with transparent background.

Windows Phone will take care of changing the color of the icon if the the user is using a light theme (so the icon will turn to black)

You can read [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff431806%28v=vs.92%29.aspx) the rules for the icons, and [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff431786%28v=vs.92%29.aspx) on how to create a new one!

Comment: So how can i make sure the icon is ALWAYS black, so that I can have a custom white app bar, no matter the Light/Dark theme?

Comment: if you set the ApplicationBar to white, the icon will probably continue to be black... but I'll have to check this one first!

Comment: ForegroundColor is the color you want for the buttons. BackgroundColor is the color of the appbar you want.

Comment: @willmel, you're absolutely correct! Thank you for pointing that out!

Comment: @WilliamMelani is it possible to customize the highlight color of appbar buttons too?

Comment: @YogeshMaheshwari do you mean the color the button turns when it is pressed?

Comment: @YogeshMaheshwari, Sorry, I don't know if that is possible. Looking at the documentation, I'd assume no. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/microsoft.phone.shell.applicationbar(v=vs.105).aspx

Answer (score 1):

**XAML**

The following XAML shows how to set the foreground and background colour and opacity of the application bar.

```
<phone:PhoneApplicationPage.ApplicationBar>
    <shell:ApplicationBar IsVisible="True" IsMenuEnabled="True" Opacity="0.75" ForegroundColor="Green" BackgroundColor="Cyan" >
        <shell:ApplicationBarIconButton IconUri="/Images/appbar_button1.png" Text="Button 1"/>
    <shell:ApplicationBarIconButton IconUri="/Images/appbar_button2.png" Text="Button 2"/>
    <shell:ApplicationBar.MenuItems>
        <shell:ApplicationBarMenuItem Text="MenuItem 1"/>
        <shell:ApplicationBarMenuItem Text="MenuItem 2"/>
    </shell:ApplicationBar.MenuItems>
    </shell:ApplicationBar>
</phone:PhoneApplicationPage.ApplicationBar>
```

**Same for C#**

```
ApplicationBar = new ApplicationBar();
    //Now set the AppBar properties :
ApplicationBar.Opacity = 0.75;
ApplicationBar.BackgroundColor = Color.FromArgb(120, 0,190,190);
ApplicationBar.ForeGroundColor = Color.FromArgb(120, 0,140, 43);
```