# How do I force Windows Phone to not recolor my App Bar Icons?

Tags: .net, windows-phone-7, xaml, windows-phone-8

I have an app I am developing and the entire theme is custom totally separate from whatever theme the user has chosen on their device. Is there a way to prevent Windows Phone from recoloring the application bar icons.  I am using a custom color here for the background color and the black looks quite bad.

I know this is possible cause the Twitter app for Windows Phone does it.  Any hints would be appreciated. Thanks

Jason

Comment: read this answer (dont forget about comments) http://stackoverflow.com/a/10196397/1616443

Comment: You tell wp "Hey! stop doing that!" ... and it will stop

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Big thanks to jimpanzer for pointing this out.

Ensures the icon is ALWAYS colored white regardless of the user's theme settings.

Very nice

Answer (score 0):

**XAML**

The following XAML shows how to set the foreground and background colour and opacity of the application bar.

```
<phone:PhoneApplicationPage.ApplicationBar>
    <shell:ApplicationBar IsVisible="True" IsMenuEnabled="True" Opacity="0.75" ForegroundColor="Green" BackgroundColor="Cyan">
    <shell:ApplicationBarIconButton IconUri="/Images/appbar_button1.png" Text="Button 1"/>
    <shell:ApplicationBarIconButton IconUri="/Images/appbar_button2.png" Text="Button 2"/>
    <shell:ApplicationBar.MenuItems>
        <shell:ApplicationBarMenuItem Text="MenuItem 1"/>
        <shell:ApplicationBarMenuItem Text="MenuItem 2"/>
    </shell:ApplicationBar.MenuItems>
    </shell:ApplicationBar>
</phone:PhoneApplicationPage.ApplicationBar>
```

**Same for C#**

```
ApplicationBar = new ApplicationBar();
    //Now set the AppBar properties :
ApplicationBar.Opacity = 0.75;
ApplicationBar.BackgroundColor = Color.FromArgb(120, 0,190,190);
ApplicationBar.ForeGroundColor = Color.FromArgb(120, 0,140, 43);
```